# How to get answer in text stream mode for my own custom chatbot?

Tags: node.js, stream, chatbot, openai-api, langchain

I've built chatbot service and each user can create his own chatbot at here. It has conversation logs functionality.

I want to get answer in text stream mode.

This is getReply() function to get answer.

```
exports.getReply = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const {
      user,
      namespace,
      messages,
      baseprompt,
      temperature,
      addContext,
      rememberconv,
      numberconv,
      addlogs,
      model,
      maxTokens,
      topP,
      bestOf,
      frequency,
      presence,
      chatId,
    } = req.body;
    let results = null;
    const query = messages[messages.length - 1].content;
    let conversation = [];
    if (numberconv > 0 && messages.length >= numberconv) {
      conversation = jsonToConversation(messages.slice(-numberconv));
    } else {
      conversation = jsonToConversation(messages);
    }

    if (!namespace || !query) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Parameter Error" });
    }
    const pinecone = new PineconeClient();

    await pinecone.init({
      environment: process.env.PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT,
      apiKey: process.env.PINECONE_API_KEY,
    });

    const pineconeIndex = pinecone.Index(process.env.PINECONE_INDEX);
    const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings({
      openAIApiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
    });
    const vectorStore = await PineconeStore.fromExistingIndex(embeddings, {
      pineconeIndex: pineconeIndex,
      namespace: new ObjectId(namespace),
    });

    const CONDENSE_PROMPT = `Given the following conversation and a follow up question, rephrase the follow up question to be a standalone question.

    Chat History:
    {chat_history}
    Follow Up Input: {question}
    Standalone question:`;

    const llm = new OpenAIChat({
      openAIApiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
      temperature: temperature,
      topP: topP,
      frequencyPenalty: frequency,
      presencePenalty: presence,
      maxTokens: maxTokens,
      modelName: model,
    });

    results = await vectorStore.similaritySearch(query, bestOf);

    if (rememberconv === "yes") {
      const SYSTEM_TEMPLATE = `${baseprompt}
      {chat_history}
      Question: {question}
      Helpful answer in markdown:`;

      const chain = ConversationalRetrievalQAChain.fromLLM(
        llm,
        vectorStore.asRetriever(),
        {
          qaTemplate: SYSTEM_TEMPLATE,
          questionGeneratorTemplate: CONDENSE_PROMPT,
          returnSourceDocuments: true,
        }
      );
      const result = chain
        .call({
          input_documents: results,
          question: query,
          chat_history: new ChatMessageHistory(conversation),
        })
        .then(async (row) => {
          let message = [
            ...messages,
            ...[{ content: row.text, role: "assistant" }],
          ];
          let historyId = chatId;
          if (addlogs === "yes") {
            if (historyId) {
              await History.updateOne(
                { botId: new ObjectId(namespace) },
                {
                  $set: {
                    messages: message,
                  },
                }
              );
            } else {
              const history = new History({
                botId: new ObjectId(namespace),
                userId: new ObjectId(user._id),
                messages: message,
              });
              await history.save();
              historyId = history._id;
            }
          }

          return res.status(200).json({ data: row, chatId: historyId });
        });
    } else {
      const SYSTEM_TEMPLATE = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(
        `${baseprompt}
      {chat_history}
      Question: {question}
      Helpful answer in markdown:`
      );

      const chain = loadQAChain(llm, {
        type: "stuff",
        prompt: SYSTEM_TEMPLATE,
      });
      const result = chain
        .call({
          input_documents: results,
          question: query,
          chat_history: [],
        })
        .then(async (row) => {
          let message = [
            ...messages,
            ...[{ content: row.text, role: "assistant" }],
          ];
          let historyId = chatId;
          if (addlogs === "yes") {
            if (historyId) {
              await History.updateOne(
                { botId: new ObjectId(namespace) },
                {
                  $set: {
                    messages: message,
                  },
                }
              );
            } else {
              const history = new History({
                botId: new ObjectId(namespace),
                userId: new ObjectId(user._id),
                messages: message,
              });
              await history.save();
              historyId = history._id;
            }
          }

          return res.status(200).json({ data: row, chatId: historyId });
        });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
};
```

And this is getReply() function in the service to use api.

```
export async function getReply(
  botId,
  messages,
  baseprompt,
  temperature,
  addContext,
  rememberconv,
  numberconv,
  addlogs,
  model,
  maxTokens,
  topP,
  bestOf,
  frequency,
  presence,
  chatId
) {
  try {
    const user = getUserInfo();
    const sendData = {
      user: user,
      namespace: botId,
      messages: messages,
      baseprompt: baseprompt,
      temperature: temperature,
      addContext: addContext,
      rememberconv: rememberconv,
      numberconv: numberconv,
      addlogs: addlogs,
      model: model,
      maxTokens: maxTokens,
      topP: topP,
      bestOf: bestOf,
      frequency: frequency,
      presence: presence,
      chatId: chatId,
    };
    const response = await instance.post("/api/chatbot/getReply", sendData);
    const data = response.data;
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

And this is fetchAnswer() function to get answer.

```
async function fetchAnswer() {
        try {
          await getReply(
            botId,
            messages,
            baseprompt,
            temperature,
            addContext,
            rememberconv,
            numberconv,
            addlogs,
            model,
            maxTokens,
            topP,
            bestOf,
            frequency,
            presence,
            chatId
          ).then((res) => {
            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
            setMessages([
              ...messages,
              ...[{ content: res.data.text, role: "assistant" }],
            ]);
            setChatId(res.chatId);
            setQuery("");
            setIsFetching(false);
            props.setIsGetAnswer(true);
          });
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
      }
```